# tracking down which translation unit internal compiler error occurred in

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild, internal-compiler-error

Let's say I'm building a reasonably large code base

where I compile a whole bunch of files in one command using a whole bunch of compiler flags in the visual c++ compiler, like this:

```
CL.exe /c /I..\..\JuceLibraryCode /I..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules /ZI /nologo /W4 /WX- /MP1 /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D DEBUG /D _DEBUG /D JUCE_UNIT_TESTS=1 /D JUCER_VS2014_78A5021=1 /D JUCE_APP_VERSION=3.0.0 /D JUCE_APP_VERSION_HEX=0x30000 /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MTd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt ..\..\Source\Main.cpp ..\..\Source\MainWindow.cpp ..\..\Source\IntroScreen.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\AnimationDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\AudioLatencyDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\AudioPlaybackDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\AudioRecordingDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\AudioSettingsDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\AudioSynthesiserDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\Box2DDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\CameraDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\ChildProcessDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\CodeEditorDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\ComponentTransformsDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\CryptographyDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\DialogsDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\FontsDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\GraphicsDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\ImagesDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\JavaScript.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\KeyMappingsDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\LiveConstantDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\LookAndFeelDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\MDIDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\MidiDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\MultithreadingDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\MultiTouch.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\NetworkingDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\OpenGLDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\OpenGLDemo2D.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\PropertiesDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\SystemInfoDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\TimersAndEventsDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\UnitTestsDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\ValueTreesDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\VideoDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\WebBrowserDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\WidgetsDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\WindowsDemo.cpp ..\..\Source\Demos\XMLandJSONDemo.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\BinaryData.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_audio_basics\juce_audio_basics.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_audio_devices\juce_audio_devices.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_audio_formats\juce_audio_formats.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_audio_processors\juce_audio_processors.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_audio_utils\juce_audio_utils.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_box2d\juce_box2d.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_core\juce_core.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_cryptography\juce_cryptography.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_data_structures\juce_data_structures.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_events\juce_events.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_graphics\juce_graphics.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_gui_basics\juce_gui_basics.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_gui_extra\juce_gui_extra.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_opengl\juce_opengl.cpp ..\..\JuceLibraryCode\modules\juce_video\juce_video.cpp
```

Let's say I get an ICE and it's in some header file that is obviously included directly or indirectly by one of the source files(translation unit), is there a way to track down which translation unit(source .cpp file) directly or indirectly(through some other head) included the header in which the ICE occurred?

The output I get in the console seems have really jumbled ordering, so much so that I cannot by looking at it easily figure out which source file included the header that had an ICE.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile with `cl /E` instead of `/c`, you'll get output (on `stdout` by default) with the following notation used when a file is first incorporated in the translation unit:

```
#line 1 "...file [path and] name..."
```

You can look for the `#line 1` line corresponding to the header in which the ICE is reported, then look back to the previous `#line`s to see which files directly and indirectly included it.

### EXAMPLE

My comments below are inline, surrounded by [[[triple brackets]]].  Remember to infer whether a source file is newly included or being "returned to" after including some other file by the line number "1" after `#line`....

```
 ~/dev/tr  cat h.h
#pragma once
h one
h two
h three
 ~/dev/tr  cat i.h
#pragma once
#include "h.h"
 ~/dev/tr  cat tr1.cpp
#include "h.h"
struct X { };
 ~/dev/tr  cat tr2.cpp
#include "i.h"
int main()
{
    X x;
}
 ~/dev/tr  cl /E tr1.cpp tr2.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

tr1.cpp
#line 1 "tr1.cpp"
#line 1 "c:\\home\\anthony\\user\\dev\\tr\\h.h"
        [[[ above line means prior context of tr1.cpp has #included h.h ]]]
#pragma once
h one
h two
h three
#line 2 "tr1.cpp"
        [[[ above line means prior context of h.h "popped", returning to
            tr1.cpp at line 2 ]]]
struct X { };
tr2.cpp
#line 1 "tr2.cpp"
#line 1 "c:\\home\\anthony\\user\\dev\\tr\\i.h"
        [[[ i.e. tr2.cpp #included i.h ]]]
#pragma once
#line 1 "c:\\home\\anthony\\user\\dev\\tr\\h.h"
        [[[ i.e. prior context of i.h #included h.h ]]]
#pragma once
h one
h two
h three
#line 3 "c:\\home\\anthony\\user\\dev\\tr\\i.h"
        [[[ i.e. i.h continues after the "include h.h" line ]]]
#line 2 "tr2.cpp"
        [[[ i.e. tr2.cpp continues after the "include i.h" line ]]]
int main()
{
    X x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this strategy doesn't seem to work when the same header is included directly or indirectly by more than one translation units.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But let's say the same header is included directly or indirectly by 10 translation units, there's still no way to track down in which translation unit the ICE occurred.

Your method I believe works when you only want to find all translation units that directly or indirectly includes some particular header.

Comment: @igbgotiz if the ICE error message (which you didn't post) doesn't do more than list the header file and it is multiply used as you've said, then it does indeed sound like you're kind of stuck.  What most people do is invoke the compiler once per translation unit... that's why they don't suffer from this problem.  I suggest you break your build process up.